# MPS error when rebuilding projects: "no output location for x@descriptor"

Tags: mps

I am new to JetBrains MPS and am trying to get a feel for Jetbrains MPS applications that others have built.  However, I am finding that I am unable to build most applications I download from GitHub. Mostly, I get errors when trying to rebuild the project.  One common error I get is:

```
no output location for x@descriptor
...
Error executing target jetbrains.mps.make.facets.Make.reconcile : no input. Stopping
```

where x is the name of the language.

what must I update to fix it?

Extra Details:

- OS: Windows 10
- MPS: 2020.2
- example git repo: https://github.com/DSLFoundry/mps-examples/Sorting

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: it's been a bit of time, but I think it was because I didn't run the gradle script that came with it to import external libraries

Comment: I am a beginner and have an issue in the imported jar (wth stubs - iText) the class coming from one package is not visible in the stubs and that's why I can't use it... Have you faced something like this?

Comment: i am also a beginner.  have you tried the slack channel? http://slack-mps.jetbrains.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another cause could be that for some reason the Java Facet has not been enabled. AFAIK between 2020.1 and 2020.3 (haven't checked 2020.2) this has become necessary for some/most languages.

The easy fix is to enable the Java Facet in the Module properties for the Language/Generator which reports "No output location for.../behaviour" etc.